# Using ping to determine which link to use

Tags: batch-file, ping

is there a way to check if a link gets a signal using the "ping" command and go to that website, and if it does not get a signal, test it for a different website and so on? This is using a batch (.bat) file. Thank you!

Comment: This would be no benefit: some sites reply to `ping`, others don't although they are online. (for example: www.ibm.com replies, www.hp.com doesn't)

Comment: @Stephan It depends on the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ERRORLEVEL after your ping command

```
ping -n 1 yoursite
if ERRORLEVEL 0 do-something-with yoursite
```

Then you need a loop so your batch file could look like

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (domains.txt) do (
    ping -w 1000 -n 1 %%A > NUL
    if ERRORLEVEL 0 if not ERRORLEVEL 1 echo %%A did reply
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 if not ERRORLEVEL 2 echo %%A did not reply
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ping -n 1 www.google.com && iexplore www.google.com || echo no ping.
```

NOTE: some sites (for example www.hp.com) don't reply to `ping`. This would give false negatives.